# Concatenate variables using expansion in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm trying to simplify a compilation line for `gcc` using exapansion variables properties of bash scripting.

Let's say I've defined a variable `SRC=src/` containing a folder of source files, and an additional variable `C_SOURCES=(source1.c source2.c ...)` countaining the source files themselves.

If I write something like `"${SRC}${C_SOURCES[@]}"`, the result is that only the first value in the `C_SOURCES` variable gets the value in `SRC`, so: `src/source1.c source2.c ...`. Which is not what I expected.

How should I rewrite the line with variable expansion so all values in `C_SOURCES` variable get the value in `SRC` variable?

Comment: Don't know if it is a typo, but `source 2.c` will be two different elements in the array unless you quote it

Comment: @SaintHax An array is a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use printf

```
C_SOURCES=('source1.c' 'source 2.c' 'source3.c' )

SRC='src/'

printf "'$SRC%s' " "${C_SOURCES[@]}"
```

outputs

```
'src/source1.c' 'src/source 2.c' 'src/source3.c'
```

Comment: Actually, it works for me if i remove the single quotation marks around the `$SRC%s` term. Thank you very much!

Comment: @EuGENE Didn't know what you want to use the end product for so yeah just tweak it to fit your purposes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PATHS=($(for x in ${C_SOURCES[@]}; do echo "$SRC/$x"; done))
```

I chose to include the `/` just to be sure.  This won't handle filenames or paths with spaces in them properly.

Comment: It does not seem to work in the `gcc` instruction, as using `echo` in a `for` loop introduces newline characters at the end of `"$SRC/$x"`. But thank you for your advice.